# jQuery not looping through image

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to fadeout / fadein my images after a set interval, the issue I'm having is that it's just constantly fading in and out of the same image rather than moving onto the next 3. Any ideas just from looking at it? it seems to me as if it should be working.

```
var LoopImage =
    {
        init: function()
        {
            //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
            var initialFadeIn = 1000;

            //interval between items (in milliseconds)
            var itemInterval = 10000;

            //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
            var fadeTime = 2500;

            //count number of items
            var numberOfItems = $('.explainerLink').length;

            //set current item
            var currentItem = 0;

            //show first item
            $('.explainerLink').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);

            //loop through the items
            var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function(){
                $('.explainerLink').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);

                if(currentItem == numberOfItems -1){
                    currentItem = 0;
                }else{
                    currentItem++;
                }
                $('.explainerLink').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);

            }, itemInterval);
        }
    };

    LoopImage.init();
```

HTML:

```
<img src="themes/base/img/img-1.png" class="active animated bounceInUp" /> 
<img src="themes/base/img/img-2.png" class="" /> 
<img src="themes/base/img/img-3.png" class="" /> 
<img src="themes/base/img/img-4.png" class="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Is there just one image ? you need to show some HTML Markup and also probably consider using the $.each function in jquery if u have more then one image !

Comment: I've added the html to the bottom.

Comment: As you say "it looks correct", but it depends on the HTML matching the expectations of the code. e.g. your `class="explainerLink"` appears to be missing from your images

Answer (score 2):

As you stated your code looks like it should work. You just need to ensure your HTML matches (e.g. has the class name present on the images):

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/kLnzqagx/1/

```
<img id="image1" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/" class="explainerLink"/><br/>
<img id="image2" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3/" class="explainerLink" /><br/>
<img id="image3" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/5/" class="explainerLink"/><br/>
```

Comment: Yeah, I think I've gone about the initial implementation wrong as I'm just looking to replace the image on fadeout rather than have both active at teh same time.

Comment: @Alexander Solonik: Just based it on a JSFiddle I found Googling "JSFiddle with images". Full credit to them :)